# How to convert single string and multiple strings to a valid set() in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, type-conversion, set

Let's assume I read the following strings out of a file:

```
s1 = "{'XXX-YYY'}"
s2 = "{'XXX-YYY', 'XXX-ZZZ', 'XXX-AAA', 'XXX-BBB'}"
```

I want convert both strings to valid sets. I tried this:

```
s1 = {s1}
s2 = set((s2, ))
```

The outcome is obviously not a valid set():

```
{"{'XXX-YYY'}"}
{"{'XXX-YYY', 'XXX-ZZZ', 'XXX-AAA', 'XXX-BBB'}"}
```

It should be:

```
{'XXX-YYY'}
{'XXX-YYY', 'XXX-ZZZ', 'XXX-AAA', 'XXX-BBB'}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Your second set is not valid, it wil only keep 'XXX-YYY' once. Is it what you want? If you want to keep all similar items, you must create a list

Comment: Sorry, I just added a wrong example, now it should be okay. My problem is obviously the string handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s1=s1.replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace("'", '')
s1=[k.strip() for k in s1.split(',')]
s1=set(s1)

s2=s2.replace('{', '').replace('}', '').replace("'", '')
s2=[k.strip() for k in s2.split(',')]
s2=set(s2)

print(s1)

{'XXX-YYY'}

print(s2)

{'XXX-YYY', 'XXX-AAA', 'XXX-BBB', 'XXX-ZZZ'}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create a set:

```
def string2set(string):
    unwanted = "{}'"
    for char in unwanted:
        string = string.replace(char, "")
    list = string.split(",")
    return set(list)

s1 = "{'XXX-YYY'}"
s2 = "{'XXX-YYY', 'XXX-YYY', 'XXX-YYY', 'XXX-YYY'}"

s1_set = string2set(s1)
s2_set = string2set(s2)
```

> s1_set = {'XXX-YYY'}

> s2_set = {'XXX-YYY', ' XXX-YYY', ' XXX-YYY', ' XXX-YYY'}